# Problem to solve fully sql mode for group by query in Ubuntu?

Tags: mysql

Group by Problem For SQL mode 
1. goto etc/mysql
2. cd mysql.conf.d/
3.  cat mysqld.cnf
4. sudo chmod 777 mysqld.cnf
5. sudo chmod 755 mysqld.cnf
6. add following contain in mysqld.cnf

[mysqld]
sql_mode=STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
#
7.  sudo service mysql restart
8. sudo service mysql status

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: Perhaps he is referencing some columns in his query which are neither wrapped in an aggregation function or listed in the GROUP BY clause.